# When did the Nuu-Chah-Nulth stop whaling?

Tags: canada

I am wondering when the [Nuu-Chah-Nulth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuu-chah-nulth) stopped whaling.

I've been looking around and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: For casual reference: The Nuu-chah-nulth are one of the indigenous peoples of the pacific northwest coast of Canada.

Answer (score 2):

> Gray whales were plentiful before “Yankee whalers” decimated the stocks, says Coté. In 1937, the US banned gray whale hunting and in 1972, the gray whale was placed on the endangered species list.
>
> The Makah and the Nuu-chah-nulth honoured the ban on whaling. *[Dominion Paper](http://www.dominionpaper.ca/articles/2622)*

Whaling halted in 1972; however as the article makes clear, whaling started again in the 21st century when the population recovered, then halted again. There is no simple answer.